# Functions to appear outside of annotations

Tags: dafny

I am going through the Dafny online tutorial (https://dafny-lang.github.io/dafny/OnlineTutorial/guide). Right after Exercise, it mentioned that functions can only appear in annotations. Thus, one cannot write:

```
var v := abs(3);
```

The tutorial also mentioned that sometimes it is convenient to use a function in real code, so one can define a function method, which can be called from real code.

So in Exercise 5, this is what I have written:

```
function max(a: int, b: int): int
{
   if a < b then b else a
}
method Testing() {
    var a := 3;
    var b := 4;
    var c := max(a,b); //seems like Dafny accept this program as oppose what was said in the tutorial
    assert a <= c && b <= c;
}
```

I was expecting an error at the line

```
var c := max(a,b);
```

However, I didnt get any error.

On the other hand, in Exercise 6, when I have the following as code:

```
function abs(x: int): int
{
   if x < 0 then -x else x
}
method Abs(x: int) returns (y: int)
    ensures y == abs(x);
{
   y := abs(x);
}
```

I have the error at the line:

```
y := abs(x);
```

stating that "function calls are allowed only in specification contexts (consider declaring the function a 'function method')".

After I changed the line `function abs(x: int): int` to `function method abs(x: int): int`, then the error is gone.

May I check why does it work in Exercise 5 but not in Exercise 6?

Anyway, may I also check what does it mean when they use the term "real code" in the phrase "to use a function in read code"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is slightly out of date. Thank you for reporting it. I have filed [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/1646) to update the tutorial and fix this.

Here is an explanation of what's going on.

As you have learned in the tutorial, Dafny makes a strong distinction between "specification contexts" (such as `requires`/`ensures` clauses, `assert` statements, and other annotations) and "real code" (any `method` that is not declared `ghost`). Certain features of Dafny are only available in specification contexts.

In older versions of Dafny, the user had to explicitly declare each variable to be `ghost` in a `method` if they wanted that variable to have access to specification-context-only features.

In modern Dafny, if the right-hand side of a variable assignment requires a specification context, then the variable is automatically declared ghost.

Thus, in Exercise 5, the code works fine because `c` is automatically declared `ghost` by Dafny. Since `c` is only used inside an assertion, everything is fine.

In Exercise 6, you are trying to return `abs` from the `method`. This is not inside an annotation but is instead "real code". (We might want to compile and run it!) Since `y` is the return parameter for `Abs`, it is *not* a ghost variable, since its value must exist at run time. So when you assign `y := abs(x)`, the right-hand side of the assignment is in a "real code" context, where it is not allowed to call `function`s like `abs`.

The fix for Exercise 6 is to declare `abs` a `function method`.